# Destructors an externally defined Class method

Tags: c++, external, destructor

I'm learning about destructors a bit, and wanted to see if this is the right way to write them externally as opposed to inside the Class.

```
class Foo
{
private:
    int* array;
    int arraySize;
public:
    Foo(int size)   // Assume "size" is > 0
    {
        arraySize = size;
        array = new int[size];
    }

    ~Foo();
};
Foo::~Foo() {
    delete array;
    delete &arraySize;
}
```

Comment: 1) Why are you deleting `arraySize`?  2) You are using the wrong form of `delete`.  It should be `delete[] array;`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie like I said, just reading up on it. The example I saw showed the destructor deleting all the data members in the class so I wasn't sure. Thanks for the tip on delete[], appreciate it

Comment: The example is wrong.  You can only `delete` a pointer value that points to the beginning of a dynamically allocated block of memory created with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a destructor outside the class definition is no difference from defining a normal function outside the class definition:

```
return_type class_name::function_name(..)
{
   ...
}
```

except that there is no return_type for destructor(and constructor).

By the way, the way you use `delete` is wrong. You should only `delete` objects that you previously allocated on heap by `new`. And deleting an array is different from deleting a single element, as you need specify explicitly.

```
Foo::~Foo() {
    delete array;      // should use delete [] to delete an array on heap
    delete &arraySize; // don't delete an object on stack, cos it's not "newed"
}
```